# mutt: how can I open a subfolder that has subfolders?

Tags: mutt

I want to start using `mutt` again after about 15 years. I first want to use it to access my gmail account. I'm running into a simple problem now: how to open a subfolder (tag in gmail) that has subfolders of its own?

When I go to `TODO/` and press enter mutt takes me into the TODO directory. I simply want to open the TODO tag. How can I do that?

[image: List of tags]

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on superuser.com?

Comment: Yes, it should. It's not a programming question.

Comment: Oops. Well, I noticed many other mutt questions on SO before I asked it here. See also the Related section on the right.

Comment: See http://www.rdrop.com/docs/mutt/manual67.html: Select the action `view-file`, which is ba default the `<space>`-key. The selection key (`<enter>` by default) will select the subfolder. (I had the same problem and was searching for a while.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view messages outside your inbox, type `c` and either type `?` to view a list of all your tags and folders, or prepend your tag with an equals sign. So, to view messages tagged 'work', you'd type `c`, then `=work`, then hit Return.

Found the info on [this post](http://lifehacker.com/5574557/how-to-use-the-fast-and-powerful-mutt-email-client-with-gmail)